# Excel VBA GetOpenFileName error on MultiSelect:=True

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting error type mismatch. Please help as I'm new to VBA macro and not sure what I'm doing. I just want the code to be able to select multiple files on search:

```
Sub Main()

On Error GoTo Error:

    'Open File to search
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    bFirstLineExtract = True
    bFirstLineLog = True
    CellRowCounter = 2
    bFound = False

    'Get First Cell Value
    CellValue = Cells(CellRowCounter, 1)

    Do Until (CellValue = "") Or (CellValue = Null)
        Open myFile For Input As #1
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, textline
                If InStr(textline, CellValue) Then
                    sCreateExtract
                    bFound = True
                End If
            Loop
        If bFound = False Then
            sCreateLog
        End If
        Close #1

        CellRowCounter = CellRowCounter + 1
        CellValue = Cells(CellRowCounter, 1)
    Loop
    Close #1

Exit Sub

Error:
    MsgBox ("Error in Main subroutine - " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use `myfile` like that. You have to loop through the collection

Answer (score 7):

Like I mentioned in the comments above

**You can't use `myfile` like that. You have to loop through the collection**

See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'Open File to search
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(myFile) Then  '<~~ If user selects multiple file
        For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
            MsgBox myFile(i)
        Next i
    Else '<~~ If user selects single file
        MsgBox myFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code but still getting error, 1st dialog box(1st file selected) 2nd dialog box(2nd file selected) 3rd dialog box error on type mismatch

Comment: Try selecting different files? I have tested the code and the above code works

Comment: 2 .txt file, 1st dialog box(path of the first file) 2nd dialog box(path of the 2nd file) 3rd dialog box error on type mismatch. I think it should not have 3rd dialog box, it should process my code above to search the contents of all the .txt files

Comment: Did you make any change to my code? Because the above code works for me

Comment: No I didnt, I just addedPrivate myFile                                  As Variant and Private i                                       As Integer on my option explicit

Comment: Can you copy the complete code to a new module and test it for me?

Comment: im not sure how to do that, but my full code is on this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175652/need-help-on-excel-macro-to-search-mulltiple-txt-dat-file

Comment: Simply inserts a new module and copy paste my code there and test it :)