# Prompt user to select multiple files and perform the same action on all files

Tags: excel, vba

The user has hundreds of text files and requires making a change in the data before saving and closing them.

Below is the code I have for a single file; how can I make it handle multiple files?

```
Sub transformTxt()
    vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.edi),*.txt") 'prompt file selection
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFileName, _
                       Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                       ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                       Other:=True, OtherChar:="*", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, _
                       Local:=True                              'open *delimited txt in excel
    
    Call Transform                                      'replace values in prompt file
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xls", _
                          FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Close                                  'save and close it
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180061/excel-vba-getopenfilename-error-on-multiselect-true

Comment: Please don't edit the question to mark it as _solved_ or to add a solution in the question body. You can accept an existing answer if it helps solving your problem and/or add your own solution (if you have one) **as an answer, not as part of the question**. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Application.FileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel) with `AllowMultiSelect = True`:

```
Sub SelectMultipleFiles()
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select the files"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All supported files", "*.txt;*.edi"
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
        .Filters.Add "EDI files", "*.edi"

        If .Show = True Then
            Dim fPath As Variant
            For Each fPath In .SelectedItems
                ' Use 'fPath' to do whatever you want.
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have inserted a simple action "columns("A:A").Entirecolumn.autofit at the row --> 'use 'fpath to do whatever you want     and the marco keep running forever without prompting error .  I select 3 text file .              would it be the problem of delimiter as "*" in the text file?

Comment: just for testing purpose.  actual action is to call a sub to do some replace string action and save.

Comment: How did you determine that this part of code keeps running forever? `AutoFit` doesn't help here. For testing, you can use something that gives visual feedback like `Debug.Print(fPath)` which will write each file path of the selected files into the Immediate Window.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"would it be the problem of delimiter as "*" in the text file?"_

Comment: thanks, it is sorted out now, i edited into the code at subject.

Comment: @ThompsonHo, Please don't edit the question to mark it as _solved_ or to include a solution. You can accept an existing answer if it helps solving your problem and/or add your own solution (if you have one) **as an answer, not as part of the question**.