# Creating Email with variable recipients

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying send email to different recipients depending on three different conditions.

If condition 1 is met the email would be sent to email01 & CC email02. If condition 2 is met then the email would be sent to email03 and CC email04, etc.

```
Sub CreatingEmailTemplate()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Sample Text" & "<br><br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample Text" & "<br><br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample Text" & "<br><br><br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample TextSample TextSample" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample Text" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample Text" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample Text" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample Text" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample Text " & "<br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample Text" & "<br><br><br>" & _
      "<b>Sample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample Text" & "<br>" & _
      "Sample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample TextSample Text<b>"
    On Error Resume Next

    'Trying to implement a variable condition 
    ' depending on what condition is met the recipient of sending emails
    ' (To & CC) would change 

    With OutMail
        .To = "SampleEmail01@abc.com"
        .CC = "SampleEmail02@abc.com" 
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Sending email to different recipients"
        .htmlBody = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        'OutMail.Display True
        .Display  'or use .Send to send automatically
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    'MsgBox "Email Send"

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Everything works and I suppose I could use three different modules to handle three different conditions but I was hoping I could combine everything in one code.

Comment: @braX instead of adding specific file as attachment is there a way to have the navigation window pop-up to choose the file you want ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382575/prompt-user-to-select-multiple-file-and-do-the-same-action-on-the-all-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the to and cc by variable and call the whole method with it like

```
Sub CreatingEmailTemplate(to_recipients  as String, cc_recipients  as string)

...

With OutMail
    .To = to_recipients  
    .CC = cc_recipients  
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Sending email to different recipients"
    .htmlBody = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    'OutMail.Display True
    .Display  'or use .Send to send automatically
End With
```

or

```
Sub CreatingEmailTemplate()

dim to_recipients  as String
dim cc_recipients  as string

if (condition1=true) then
    to_recipients = "email01"
    cc_recipients = "email02"
elseif (condition2=true) then
    to_recipients = "email03"
    cc_recipients = "email04"
elseif (condition3=true) then
    to_recipients = "email01"
    cc_recipients = "email04"
else

end if

...

With OutMail
    .To = to_recipients  
    .CC = cc_recipients  
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Sending email to different recipients"
    .htmlBody = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    'OutMail.Display True
    .Display  'or use .Send to send automatically
End With
```

Comment: Works like a charm (second option) thank you very much

Comment: your solution works great however I would like to have navigation window pop-up to choose the file you want any ideas how can this be achieved in your code ?