# Copying data with different columns and sheet name from multiple workbooks - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, hssfworkbook

Hi I tried searching for possible solutions for my question but i can't find the exact code that I needed.

I need to copy a data from two different workbooks with different worksheets name and also different columns. I used my code when copying a data from a single workbook but there is an error saying

> "Automation error".

So what I need to do is to copy the data from sheet name `Raw Data` and `Arm Checklist` to my main worksheet also named as `Raw Data`.

The columns that I need to copy from `Raw Data` is from `A7:Q` and to `Arm Checklist` is from `C3:D,G,E,H:J,K,M:Q`. The data from this columns needs to be combine to my MainWorkfile `Raw Data`

```
Sub SAMPLE()        
    Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
    Dim OtherWorkfile As Workbook
    Dim OtherWorkfile2 As Workbook
    Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
    Dim FilterSht As Worksheet
    Dim FilterSht2 As Worksheet

    Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' set workbook object
    Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook

    ' set the worksheet object
    Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")
    With TrackerSht
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
        .Range("A7:S7" & lRow).ClearContents
    End With


    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    ' set the 2nd workbook object
    Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

    ' set the 2nd worksheet object
    Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")

    With FilterSht
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

        .Range("A7:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("A7:Q" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    OtherWorkfile.Close

    Set OtherWorkfile2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

    ' set the 2nd worksheet object
    Set FilterSht2 = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Arm Checklist")

    With FilterSht2
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

        .Range("C3:D" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("A:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ' implement it for the rest of your columns...
    With FilterSht2
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

        .Range("G3:G" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("C7:C" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    With FilterSht2
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

        .Range("E3:E" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("E7:E" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With FilterSht2
        If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

        .Range("H3:J" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
    End With

    ' paste
    TrackerSht.Range("F7:H" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    OtherWorkfile2.Close



End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get your error? In which line? Use the debugger.

Comment: I did get the error when i tried to add this code 
"Set OtherWorkfile2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)" for my 2nd workbook to select and copy the data needed but i think vba can't read this kind of code.

Comment: I just tried the code and this line works just fine for me. I think it is another line. did you go step-by-step through your code?

Comment: I found your error. It is in Line "Set FilterSht2 = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Arm Checklist")". Edit it to "Set FilterSht2 = OtherWorkfile2.Sheets("Arm Checklist")" and it should run.

Comment: Also change your line "TrackerSht.Range("A:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False" to "TrackerSht.Range("A1:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False".

Comment: And you should add "    Application.ScreenUpdating = True" and "Application.DisplayAlerts = True" and "Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True" at the end of your code as it is left false and problems might occur.

Comment: @Kajkrow okay i will try this first and give you feedback.

Comment: @Kajkrow it is running but the second workbook that needs to be copied does not copy in my mainworkfile. I don't know how can i add it after the data is been copied from the first workbook. Maybe this part of my code is wrong "TrackerSht.Range("A1:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False" because it overlaps the first data that has been copied to this ranges.

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand what your problem is but I think you have to adjust your starting point: "TrackerSht.Range("A7:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False"

Comment: Hi @Kajkrow my problem is that i don't know exactly the code i need to use because the data that is been copied overlaps to the first data. Here is the scenario i am talking about, the first data comes from "Raw Data" will be copied after that "Arm Checklist" will be copied next but what is the code is doing is overlapping the data from "Raw Data" to "Arm Checklist". Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: So all you need to do is to adjust your range-values. if your data is ovrelapping at least one range is not right. to adjust your ranges you have to change the values of  "TrackerSht.Range("" & lRow)" Inside the quotation marks you have to put the range e.g. "E7:E", "A7:B". Those ranges have to be adjusted. I cannot do that for you bc I don't know where you want to put what data.

Comment: Can i make it automatic? or to use lastrow? because the data is not always the same volume so if i will set the range to "TrackerSht.Range("A20:B" & lRow)" then the data from the first workbook is more than 20 it will overlap.

Comment: how about that: add "dim lstrow as long" to the beginning of your code. then change your "TrackerSht.Range("A20:B" & lRow)" to "TrackerSht.Range("A" & lstRow & ":B" & lRow)" and include before each of those statements "lstRow = TrackerSht.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row" didnt test it but might work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174478/discussion-between-aicirtap-and-kajkrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, so here's my attempt to solve your problem:

```
Sub conso()

Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
Dim myFiles As Variant
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim OtherWorkfile(1 To 2) As Workbook
Dim CorrectionHandler(1 To 2) As Workbook
Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
Dim FilterSht As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer

Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

' set workbook object
Set MainWorkfile = ThisWorkbook

' set the worksheet object
Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")
With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' last row with data in column "C"
End With

On Error GoTo ErrHand

TryAgain:
myFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

If UBound(OtherWorkfile) > 2 Then
    MsgBox "Too many WBs selected"
    GoTo TryAgain
End If

For i = LBound(myFiles) To UBound(myFiles)
    Set OtherWorkfile(i) = Workbooks.Open(myFiles(i))
Next i
'Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename())
'currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
'Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(currentPath & "\OtherWB2.xls")


On Error GoTo correction
GoTo jumper
correction:
Set CorrectionHandler(2) = OtherWorkfile(1)
Set CorrectionHandler(1) = OtherWorkfile(2)
Set OtherWorkfile(1) = CorrectionHandler(1)
Set OtherWorkfile(2) = CorrectionHandler(2)
On Error GoTo ErrHand
jumper:

' set the 2nd worksheet object
Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile(1).Sheets("Arm Checklist")

On Error GoTo ErrHand

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("C3:D" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("A7:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' implement it for the rest of your columns...
With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("G3:G" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("C7:C" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("E3:E" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("E7:E" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("H3:J" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("F7:H" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("K3:K" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("L7:L" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("M3:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("M7:Q" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

OtherWorkfile(1).Close
'----------------------------2nd Workbook-------------------------------------

With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' last row with data in column "C"
End With


Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

'Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
'currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
'Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(currentPath & "\OtherWB.xls")
Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile(2).Sheets("Raw Data")

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("A7:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

OtherWorkfile(2).Close

ErrHand:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then                    'could use 1004 here

        MsgBox "You Choose to Cancel"
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Description

    End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

As you can see, now everything is in 1 sub.
It is possible to separate it into 2 subs, that doesn't make much sense as you would always have to use both subs. (bc the 2nd sub would be called like this:
    call conso2(otherworkfile(2))
so you cannot use the 2nd sub w/o an inputvar.

Comment: I have just gone over the code again and found some minor mistakes. I corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i came up, if anyone have any other idea on how can i pick my workbooks as one, because for now whenever i run it the "Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)"
I need to choose twice for me to be able to select the two workbooks that i need to consolidate.

```
Sub conso1()

Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
Dim OtherWorkfile2 As Workbook
Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
Dim FilterSht2 As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' set workbook object
Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook

' set the worksheet object
Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")
With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' last row with data in column "C"
End With


Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


On Error GoTo ErrHand:
'Set OtherWorkfile2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set OtherWorkfile2 = Workbooks.Open(currentPath & "\OtherWB2.xls")

' set the 2nd worksheet object
Set FilterSht2 = OtherWorkfile2.Sheets("Arm Checklist")


With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("C3:D" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("A7:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' implement it for the rest of your columns...
With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("G3:G" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("C7:C" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("E3:E" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("E7:E" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("H3:J" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("F7:H" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("K3:K" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("L7:L" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With FilterSht2
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("M3:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("M7:Q" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

OtherWorkfile2.Close

ErrHand:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then                    'could use 1004 here

        MsgBox "You Choose to Cancel"
        Err.clear
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Description

    End If


Call conso2

End Sub


Sub conso2()

Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
Dim OtherWorkfile As Workbook
Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
Dim FilterSht As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' set workbook object
Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook

' set the worksheet object
Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")
With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' last row with data in column "C"
End With


Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

On Error GoTo ErrHand:
'Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)
currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(currentPath & "\OtherWB.xls")
Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Raw Data")

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("A7:Q" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


OtherWorkfile.Close

ErrHand:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then                    'could use 1004 here

        MsgBox "You Choose to Cancel"
        Err.clear
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Description

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: to automatically choose the workbook you could hardcode the path or if the wbs are in the same folder as the wb your are starting the macro from you could use "currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path" for the path adn then add "\XXX.xlsx" for the according wbs.

Comment: @Kajkrow can you teach me how can i implement that currentPath in my codes? Thank you.

Comment: I made an edit to your answer. it should work. you need the exact file name (replace OtherWB(2)) and fileending (xls/xlsm).

Comment: hi @Kajkrow question can i use Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename) to select this two workbooks that i need?

Comment: well this is what you had before. that's why it it works too. But I thought you wanted to avoid the manuel selection of the workbooks.

Comment: oh... I think now I get it. You want to choose only one Workbook on any path and the 2nd WB is in the same folder, but you don't want to choose the path again. is that right? tell me if I'm wrong or not and than I will show you the solution.

Comment: Hi @Kajkrow I need to choose the two workbooks at the same time by using Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename), your first solution is okay but every time i need to feed the raw file i also need to change the filename because there is always a changes in the raw filename. Could you please help me?

Comment: as far as I know you cannot choose two files at a single time via workbooks.open. let me think about it. I might come up with a solution.

Comment: @Kajkrow thank you so much for your help, i'll get in touch for your solution until now i am searching on how can i do that.

Comment: so i found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180061/excel-vba-getopenfilename-error-on-multiselect-true . so it is possible to multi select, but than you have a array which you have to handle. since you do use 2 different subs another workaround is necessary or your 2 subs need to be 1 sub. I'll work on that and give you an answer.